Vite React application backend can't access localhost:3000 server
I'm building a react application using Vite, and for the backend database I'm using MySQL but not with directly connection, I'm using Prisma to deal with my DB, and I'm using SRC architecture with RESTful API to deal with the Apis, My problem is whenever I'm trying to test the API's through postman it gives me Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 It seems that when I run my Vite application, the localhost 3000 server doesn't start with it in vs code, how to fix this?
note: before a while I made a backend application using Restful API approach and test it using postman and everything was great so I know that I'm putting the right route in it, also I tried to connect with my DB and Prisma fetches the info successfully from my localhost DB and print it on console so it seems that it's not the problem.
Things I tried:

Changed 3000 port,
Changed user and password for my localhost DB
Tried another application routers in my POSTMAN and they work (not Vite)
add inbound rule for 3000 port in my network proxy settings
delete node modules


I think you need to start your backend server independently, usually with a command like: node server.js

ok but when I want to run vite I have to exit the backend server then run the vite app again

Hey OP please can add the terminal output you see when you run the vite server. For example, the output of 'yarn dev' if you're using yarn.

What is SRC architecture?

Try using Postman to send an API request directly to Prisma to access the database. This bypasses Vite. What happens?

Try starting your MySQL server in one VS Code terminal, then create a new terminal and run Vite.

@M455 the problem is when I want to start the backend server, the hierarchy of my folders is the project folder that named "Learnify" then -->  {.vscode, packages, node_modules, prisma->schema.prisma , .env and src file that handles the node.js and backend  src--> api --> routers, controllers, services and main.js file contains the backend code connection with DB, but when I run it alone it encounters an error because the prisma is using a .env file which have the database url to connect to it, and but the main.js can't see it because it's outside of his hierarchy

my mistake, SRC is not an architecture it's a common practice to keep the codebase organized, maintainable, and scalable when using express framework in node.js
